# Milne Algebraic Geometry - Remark 3.14 confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Milne's [algebraic geometry notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ag.html), he mentions

> Remark 3.14
>   The local ring $\mathcal{O}_{V,P}$ is an integral domain if $P$ lies on a single irreducible component of $V$...
>
> ... if $P$ lies on more than one irreducible component of $V$, then $\mathcal{O}_P$ contains more than one minimal prime ideal, and so the ideal $(0)$ can't be prime.

Why does having more than one minimal prime ideal mean $(0)$ cannot be prime? I'm probably missing something obvious...

---

Thanks in advance ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(0)$ is prime. If $P$ is a non-zero prime ideal, then $(0)\subsetneq P,$ so $P$ cannot be a minimal prime ideal. Hence if $(0)$ is prime then $(0)$ is the unique minimal prime ideal. Contrapositive: if there is more than one minimal prime ideal, then $(0)$ cannot be prime.

Comment: Aaaah, that is obvious. I knew I was missing something simple!

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: In fact, this is part of a more general characterization of integral domains. For a ring $A,$ the following are equivalent: (i) $A$ is an integral domain, i.e., $(0)$ is prime; (ii) $A$ has exactly one minimal prime ideal and zero is the only nilpotent element.